# MVC 3: Passing multiple queries to a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have two queries in an AggregateModel, and I'd like them to be passed through to the index view to be used in two separate foreach loop. But as of the moment they are both being passed through in one model.

The Model

```
public class AggregateModel
{
    public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
var model = new AggregateModel();
model.Tasks = db.Task.Where(n => (n.UserId == UserID) && (n.Completed == false) && (n.Due < dateTime)).ToList();
model.Events = db.Events.Where(n => (n.UserId == UserID) && (n.Start < dateTime)).ToList();

return View(model);
```

This is the majority if the view, with the redundant bits removed:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectApp.Models.AggregateModel>

<div id="upcoming-tasks">
    <h4>Your Upcoming Tasks</h4>

    <ul class="upcoming">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Tasks)
    {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Details", new { id = item.TaskId })</li>
    }
    <li>Add a @Html.ActionLink("Task", "Create", "Task")</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="upcoming-events">
    <h4>Your Upcoming Events</h4>

    <ul class="upcoming">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Events)
    {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Details", new { id = item.EventId })</li>
    }
    <li>Add a @Html.ActionLink("Task", "Create", "Task")</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see, the foreach loop calls Model, which has two queries in it. I would like to have two loops each running one of the queries.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I can see only a single loop in your view which won't compile by the way as your model doesn't implement `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Yes I only put one loop in the example as both are the same, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Is it good form to have your controller defining what these queries are?  I would put the query in the model code, and just have the controller pass in the arguments.  That way you can build a unit test for your model, instead of trying to unit test your controller

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the top of your view you should have:

```
@model AggregateModel
```

and not

```
@model IEnumerable<Task>
```

Then you can loop:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Tasks)
{
}

...

@foreach (var item in Model.Events)
{
}
```

and because looping in view is ugly you should use editor/display templates which will simplify your code to:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Tasks)
...
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Events)
```

where you should define the corresponding `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Task.cshtml` and `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Event.cshtml` templates which will be rendered for each element of the collection.

Comment: Yeah I have this at the top: @model IEnumerable<ProjectApp.Models.AggregateModel>.... the .Tasks and .Events can't be found though

Comment: @dalehumphries, you should have `@model ProjectApp.Models.AggregateModel` as I stated in my answer and not `@model IEnumerable<ProjectApp.Models.AggregateModel>`. Then you will have access to the `Tasks` and `Events` properties.

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood your problem, but the solution to what I think your problem is, is this :)

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Tasks)
{
}
```

and

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Events)
{
}
```

Comment: I looks like you understand the problem, but I have tried that and gotten red lines under the ".Tasks" and ".Events".