# mvc 3: multiple queries

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Regarding the answer [MVC 3: Passing multiple queries to a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824264/mvc-3-passing-multiple-queries-to-a-view) I realized that this way keep the mysql server connection opened.

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This will not keep your connection open. Dispose of your context when done with it. Calling .ToList() forces execution of the query *at that time* so beyond that the context will manage the lifetime of the connection so just dispose it when done in your controller after calling .ToList() as both queries do

Comment: I did a test with a new project, created the edmx and wrote the controler code as simple as it can be using (var db = new ictwebEntities())
           {
               var query = from x in db.emails
                           where x.site == "acquatica"
                           select x;
               return View(query.ToList());   
           } but the problem still happend.

Comment: But your connection is no longer used inside your view once you call ToList(). It can't be unless you are doing something else. Why do you care about when it is closed though? The connection can remain open from the .net connection pool as long as it determines it to. Your next request could easily use this same connection. Opening a connection is _very_ expensive so it keeps them open a bit in case someone else wants to use it.  Some brief info on mysql connection pooling with .net: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662409/mysql-net-connection-pool-connection-open-very-slow